# Horizontal line after certain items no matter the visibilities

Tags: css

I have a list comprised of 2 types of items, the items are always grouped, not mixed. Like:

```
a
a
a
b
b
b
```

How can I show a separator between the `a` items and the `b` items, a horizontal line. But how can I make that work even if some items have display: none.

For example:

```
a
a
a
(Show line here)
b
b
b
```

```
a
a
a
b [display: none]
(Show line here)
b
b
```

```
a
a
(Show line here)
a [display: none]
b
b
b
```

Is this possible with css only in a way that is not incredibly hacky?

For now I'm doing this manually with javascript.

Using border-top or border-bottom on first/last items is not a solution because when styled, the style touches the border, it looks off, I want the line to be completely separated. I guess a pseudo element, but not if it means using position: absolute hacks (unless it's pretty simple).

What I do with javascript:

```js
App.check_pinline = () => {
  App.remove_pinline()
  let last_pinned

  for (let item of App.get_items(`tabs`)) {
    if (!item.visible) {
      continue
    }

    if (item.pinned) {
      last_pinned = item
    }
    else {
      if (!last_pinned) {
        return
      }
      else {
        let pinline = DOM.create(`div`, `pinline`)
        last_pinned.element.after(pinline)
        return
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: is it always the first item of the second group that might be hidden in the second group? Is there only one element that can be hidden or can it be few?

Comment: Using absolute positioning should be pretty simple in such a situation, and I would not consider it to be a "hack" either.

Comment: @AmauryHanser it can be any item. It's a filter, any item might be visible or hidden.

Comment: @CBroe I'm open to seeing a solution with it.

Comment: You said you've done it with js, I think you should show us your code so we can understand the situation better

Comment: @Damzaky I edited the question with js

Comment: Basically I check what's the last kind of item `a` (or pins) then insert a `pinline` there. Ignoring non-visibles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solvable with simple `:not` and two rules (i.e. without modern `:has` that is yet about to be implemented in stable Firefox).

First rule that assigns separator to all visible `.b`'s following any visible `.a`, and then second that takes that separator away from all `.b`'s after any visible `.b`. For demonstrative purposes using simple `border-top: solid;` -- using `::before { content: ''; display: block; border-top: solid; }`or similar instead would work the same.

```css
.a:not([hidden]) ~ .b:not([hidden]) {
  border-top: solid;
}

.a:not([hidden]) ~ .b:not([hidden]) ~ .b {
  border-top: none
}

/* demo */
body { counter-reset: figs; }
figure { counter-increment: figs; counter-reset: as bs;}
figcaption::before { content: 'Fig 'counter(figs) ' - '; }
p { margin: 0; --m: 'visible';}
[hidden] { display: block !important; opacity: 0.3; --m: ' hidden';}
p::before { content: attr(class) '#'; }
.a { counter-increment: as; }
.b { counter-increment: bs; }
.a::after { content: counter(as) ' ' var(--m); }
.b::after { content: counter(bs) ' ' var(--m); }
```

```html
<figure>
  <figcaption>Everything visible:</figcaption>
  <p class="a"></p>
  <p class="a"></p>
  <p class="a"></p>
  <p class="b"></p>
  <p class="b"></p>
  <p class="b"></p>
</figure>

<figure>
  <figcaption>First <code>.b</code> hidden:</figcaption>
  <p class="a"></p>
  <p class="a"></p>
  <p class="a"></p>
  <p class="b" hidden></p>
  <p class="b"></p>
  <p class="b"></p>
</figure>

<figure>
  <figcaption>Last <code>.a</code> hidden:</figcaption>
  <p class="a"></p>
  <p class="a"></p>
  <p class="a" hidden></p>
  <p class="b"></p>
  <p class="b"></p>
  <p class="b"></p>
</figure>
<figure>
  <figcaption>All but first and last hidden:</figcaption>
  <p class="a"></p>
  <p class="a" hidden></p>
  <p class="a" hidden></p>
  <p class="b" hidden></p>
  <p class="b" hidden></p>
  <p class="b"></p>
</figure>
<figure>
  <figcaption>only <code>.a</code>'s visible</figcaption>
  <p class="a" hidden></p>
  <p class="a"></p>
  <p class="a"></p>
  <p class="b" hidden></p>
  <p class="b" hidden></p>
  <p class="b" hidden></p>
</figure>
<figure>
  <figcaption>only <code>.b</code>'s visible</figcaption>
  <p class="a" hidden></p>
  <p class="a" hidden></p>
  <p class="a" hidden></p>
  <p class="b"></p>
  <p class="b" hidden></p>
  <p class="b"></p>
</figure>
```

Could be written even more simple alternatively, leaving separators even on "hidden" `.b`s:

```
.a:not([hidden]) ~ .b {
  border-top: solid;
}

.b:not([hidden]) ~ .b {
  border-top: none
}
```

---

Expanding this idea with `flex` and `order` to super simple *pin (up) and filter items and separate them with separator if it make sense* doodle:

```js
document.body.addEventListener(
  'click',
  function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt?.tagName != 'BUTTON') return;
    tgt.parentElement.style.order *= -1;
  }
);

function filter(str) {
  document.querySelectorAll('span').forEach(
    e => e[(e.textContent.includes(str) ? 'remove' : 'set') + 'Attribute']('hidden', ''));
};
```

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1em inset;
}

hr {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1em outset;
}

:not([hidden]):not([style^="order: -"])
 ~ :not([hidden])[style^="order: -"] ~ hr ,
:not([hidden])[style^="order: -"]
 ~ :not([hidden]):not([style^="order: -"]) ~ hr {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" oninput="filter(this.value)" placeholder="zonk">
<div style="">
  <span style="order:  1"><button>⇅</button> foo</span>
  <span style="order: -1"><button>⇅</button> bar</span>
  <span style="order: -1"><button>⇅</button> baaz</span>
  <span style="order:  1"><button>⇅</button> gazonk</span>
  <span style="order:  1"><button>⇅</button> qux</span>
  <span style="order:  1"><button>⇅</button> quux</span>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Using real `<hr>`, because, after all, it is probably the right element to use here.

Answer (score 1):

This highly depends on the HTML structure that you have and how you hide the elements (you didn't include it in your question, so this is just my assumption). I'd suggest just use `::after` pseudo element on the last visible element of the same kind.

If the `display: none` is from inline style:

```css
.a:not(:has(~ .a:not([style*='display: none']))):not([style*='display: none'])::after {
    content: '';
    height: 1px;
    background: black;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
case 1
<div>
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="b">b</div>
  <div class="b">b</div>
  <div class="b">b</div>
  <div class="b">b</div>
</div>
<br>
case 2
<div>
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="b" style="display: none;">b</div>
  <div class="b">b</div>
  <div class="b">b</div>
  <div class="b">b</div>
</div>
<br>
case 3
<div>
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="a" style="display: none;">a</div>
  <div class="b">b</div>
  <div class="b">b</div>
  <div class="b">b</div>
  <div class="b">b</div>
</div>
```

The selector

```
.a:not(:has(~ .a:not([style*='display: none']))):not([style*='display: none'])
```

just means to select class `a` that has no next siblings with class `a` that has no `style="display: none"` and it also has no `style="display: none"` itself. If you hide the element with, for instance, `.hidden` class, then you can change the `[style*='display: none']` with `.hidden`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do in fact use a .hidden class. And the `a` item in my case is called `pin_item`. So this is what I'm trying `.pin_item:not(:has(~ .pin_item:not(.hidden))):not(.hidden) {`  Which doesn't work, but also the embedded demo on this site from your answer is not showing anything either. Not sure if it's a firefox limitation.

Comment: Forgot to add ::after but still with it still doesn't work

Comment: The embed does work in chromium.

Comment: yeah this seems to only work on chromium-based browser as of now, I don't think there's another pure CSS solution for this, imo, as of now your solution with javascript is much more viable

Comment: General side note about browser features: before raising an issue in browser's issue tracker, check MDN support tables  and Caniuse Resources tab, there will be very likely direct link to existing (tracking) issue for given feature where you should be able get most recent info.
https://caniuse.com/css-has / https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has